# What is the closest to “I am really pissed off”?

Tags: anglais, vulgarité

*J'en ai marre*, *j'en ai assez* are too mild... *ça me fait chier* seems just too strong, is there something in between?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some alternatives in between commonly used in France (but not idiomatic in Canadian French) :

- *Ça me gave !*
- *Ça me saoule !*
- *Ça me gonfle !*

Note that depending on the tone and the context *ça me fait chier* might not be that strong.

Comment: None of those would be acceptable in Quebec. "Ca me fait chier" I think is international and also what I would use in most cases.

Comment: @ApplePie Do you mean they would be unacceptable for being too strong or for being non idiomatic?

Comment: Sorry, I mean non idiomatic. Nobody would say this.

Comment: @Qu'arrhesrententsanshune La question ne précise pas si elle se limite à la France ou est plus générale, j'ai donc ajouté l'explication entre parenthèses pour tenir compte du commentaire d'ApplePie. Quand j'écris, *not that strong*, c'est d'une manière générale. *Ça me fait chier* n'est pas aussi grossier que l'on ne pourrait l'imaginer, exactement comme *to piss someone off* est, à ma connaissance, moins grossier que *to piss* en anglais.

Answer (score 2):

Although it’s not vulgar, to the extent that the state of being pissed/ticked off resembles being in “un état de nervosité accompagné d'impatience ou d'irritation,” you could consider the single word [“agacer”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agacer), or for a more slangy expression (at the same link to *CNRTL-TFLi*), “Agacer le système”:

> Ça/il/tu m'agace/s.
>
> Ça/il/tu m'agace/s le système.

Some variations using different verbs and/or objects from different parts of the francophone world and with different degrees of slanginess might include :

[Courir / taper](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/courir-taper-sur-le-systeme-le-haricot.php) / tomber / pogner …
sur (à ras) …
les rognons / les nerfs / le système [nerveux] / le haricot / le gros nerf.

(“courir/taper sur le système/haricot” from the *expressio.fr*;
 “tomber sur (à ras) les rognons/le gros nerf” from my hard copy of Pierre DesRuisseaux’s *Dictionnaire des expressions québécoises*; and
[“pogner les nerfs”](https://quebechisme.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/sur-le-gros-nerf/) from *quebechisme.wordpress.com*)

---

Concerning your hesitation to use *ça me fait chier*, if by “[It] just seems too strong” you’re referring to (as I think you are) the level/strength of annoyance/agitation expressed by that phrase (and not its level/strength of vulgarity), I get what you’re saying, but I also agree with the observation noted in [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27384/what-is-the-closest-to-i-am-really-pissed-off/27385#27385) “that **depending on the tone and the context** *ça me fait chier* might not be that strong” (which I interpret, read together with the comments below it, to mean “… [it] might not be too strong to use to capture either/both the level of annoyance/agitation or/and the level of vulgarity expressed by “I’m really pissed off”).

Anyway, if your hesitation nevertheless does persist and if it does in fact involve *ça me fait chier*’s  “level of annoyance” (and not its level of vulgarity), perhaps you could still consider using this interesting French notion by at least appearing to be toning the current level of your annoyance back to its nascency  (while at the same time clearly warning that things can/will get worse if the annoyance continues) by prefacing it, just as is often the case with “piss off” in English, with [“commencer {vraiment} à](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/commencer) as follows:

> Ça/tu commence/s [vraiment] à me faire chier.
>       (I’m [really] starting to get pissed off [at you].//You’re [really] starting to piss me off.)

Please note that this placement of “vraiment” and “really” (if used/really needed at all) is intended to add emphasis to "commence/s à" and "starting to" and not (at least directly) to what follows them for, at least in the French version, what follows them wouldn’t need further emphasis to mean “pissed off,” in my opinion.

See the above link to *CNRTL-TFLi* entry for “commencer” for a discussion and examples of this particular familiar use of “commencer à”
(when the subject is a person="Tu commences à me faire chier"):

I.− Emploi trans.
A.− [Le suj. désigne une pers. considérée comme agent de l'action de commencer]

2. [Le compl. d'obj. est un verbe à l'inf. précédé d'une prép.]
   − Fam. [Pour marquer qu'on est à bout de patience et que le mécontentement est encore susceptible de croître si ce qui le provoque ne cesse pas] Tu commences à m'agacer, mon garçon! Je n'ai d'ordres à recevoir de personne, ici (H. BAZIN, Vipère au poing,1948, p. 264).Le commissaire commençait à en avoir chaud aux oreilles (SIMENON, Les Vacances de Maigret,1948, p. 119).

(and when the subject is a thing= "Ça commence à me faire chier"):

I.− Emploi trans.
B.− [Le suj. désigne une chose susceptible d'action ou de développement, en vertu de sa nature propre ou de sa finalité]

2. [Le compl. d'obj. est un verbe à l'inf. précédé d'une prép.]
   − Fam. [Pour exprimer l'impatience (cf. supra I A 2)] Foin! Foin! Tu me l'as fait répéter dix mille fois. Ça commence à me sortir par les yeux (AUDIBERTI, Le Mal court,1947, I, p. 150)

Comment: @Qu'arrhesrententsanshune I should have added "vraiment" to all of them to fully account for the OP's "really."///Your "tout seul" version certainly is a way to avoid the confusion you mention, but **maybe** the literal "It/That really gets on my nerves" translation could be reserved for expressing "simple", pre-anger annoyance w/someone (or just w/something in general like the sound of nails on a chalkboard), whereas "You/that really piss/es me off" might be better in contexts when the annoyance has progressed to anger (especially when directed at the person causing the annoyance). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, more like _énerver_, you're right... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A very appropriate one would be:

> J'en ai [ras le bol](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ras-le-bol/66576).

It is quite strong, but socially acceptable. As a noun, it is also frequently used in conjunction with political protests:

> Les infirmiers ont défilé dans les rues de Paris pour exprimer leur **ras-le-bol**.

Answer (score 1):

Au Québec à tout le moins, on a la locution verbale ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maudit/1); aussi au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/maudit#Nom_commun) avec *contre qqn.*, de même sens) *être en maudit*, qui est parfaitement usuelle à la première personne du singulier (*I'm really pissed off*/*It really pisses me off*) et plutôt courante à mon avis :

> Je suis (vraiment) en maudit. [en colère, fâché]

On peut aussi faire précéder *maudit* de l'adjectif *beau* (*en beau maudit*). Une panoplie d'autres termes peuvent se substituer à *maudit* (par exemple [*fusil*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_en_fusil) pour *furieux*, ainsi que diverses atténuations du mot, comme [*mautadit*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mautadit) etc.). Par ailleurs, si on remplace [*maudit*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Maudit) par *certains* autres sacres/jurons ([par exemple](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/crisse#Nom_commun)) ce sera d'un registre plus populaire voire vulgaire...

Answer (score 0):

There is more familiar expressions like :

- J'en ai ras le bol
- J'en ai plein le cul
- Je sature

Comment: Welcome to FLE. I wouldn't say *j'en ai plein le cul* is "milder" than *ça me fait chier*. Both are on the same language register.